# Replace word in row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need replace word in row in sql server table.
I've table

```
id           value

1            K-Numbers  

2            J-Number  

3            L-Number
```

I need to replace values in value column. In result

```
id           value

1            K-Value

2            J-Value

3            L-Value
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

As you've written the question, this would appear to be the answer:

```
update t
    set value = replace(replace(value, 'Numbers', 'Value'), 'Number', 'Value');
```

Is that what you really need?